# ActiveMQ: In memory scheduler with replicated leveldb

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using replicated levelDB in ActiveMQv5.11.1. I have a use case of delayed message handling. I have gone through the documentation and it looks like I can't use it with leveldb (Only kahadb supports scheduler)

I have also seen couple of posts about In-memory scheduler (https://dzone.com/articles/coming-activemq-v511-memory) but I think I need to run the broker with persistent=false.

Is there a way I can use In memory scheduler with replicated levelDB ?

Thanks,
Anuj

Answer (score 0):

When using LeveDB if you've enabled scheduler support and you have the activemq-kahadb-store jar on the classpath the broker will still create a Job Scheduler store as the default store is based on KahaDB but is not intrinsically tied to it so it can be created standalone.

There are also some setters in the broker service where you can set the scheduler store you want to use as well.